Grafana Promtail: Remove ANSI coloring with decolorize before parsing
The transformation stage is executed after the parsing stage. This makes the  decolorize processing not useful in my opinion. I need a cleaned message before the parsing phase. To extract my fields in a regex I have to include the ANSI coloring noise, this is not good.

How to clean the message before the parsing?
I'm using rsyslog, can rsyslog be configured to clean the message before sending it to promtail syslog?

What I want to parse:

#033[90m2024-05-20T20:44:29Z#033[0m | INFO  | #033[1mHTTP response headers: map[Cache-Control:[must-revalidate] Content-Length:[247] Content-Type:[application/json] Date:[Mon, 20 May 2024 20:44:28 GMT] Server:[CouchDB/3.3.3 (Erlang OTP/24)] X-Couch-Request-Id:[107da8>

My processing pipeline:
    - match:
        selector: '{application="couchdb"}'
        stages:
        - decolorize:
        - regex:
            expression: '#\d+?\[\d+?m(?P<timestamp>[\w:-]*?)#\d+?\[\d+?m\s+?\|\s+?(?P<level>[A-Z]+)\s+?\|\s+?#\d+?\[\d+?m(?P<message>.*)#?\d*?\[?\d*?m?'
        - labels:
            level:
            facility:
        - timestamp:
            format: RFC3339
            source: timestamp
        - output:
            source: message


A general rule is to tweak logs as close to the app as possible. So, try changing your app's logging format instead of doing so via Promtail.

@Rohlik This is in general not possible. I cannot modify the log format of all third party apps I do not have under control. If they use ANSI coloring then this must be handled. The only central instance I see being able to control this is a potential syslog parameter which might not exist

This just works for me, and then I can do whatever I want with the logs. e.g. calculating metrics:
  pipeline_stages:
  - decolorize:
  - regex:
      expression: 'REQUEST FINISHED:.*-\s(?P<latency>\d+)ms$'
      action: keep
  - metrics:
      insly_request_latency_ms:
        type: Histogram
        description: "Histogram of request latencies (ms)"
        source: latency
        config:
          buckets: [100, 250, 500, 1000, 5000, 10000, 30000, 60000]

https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/send-data/promtail/stages/decolorize/
